# How to get user input PIC assembly

Tags: assembly, user-input, pic, microchip

I'm having a problem with an assembly program that I have previously written here about. So the problem is

> R = 23 + A.6 - 101

How can I get `A` to be input by the user? Also, how can I get the allocation of data memory with the participating variables. Here is my code as posted previously.

```
LIST P=16C73A
    #INCLUDE <P16C73A.inc> ;
    ORG 0 ;PROGRAM MEMORY ADDRESS =0x0000
    GOTO MAIN

N1      EQU 70      
RL      EQU 71      
RH      EQU 72      

    ORG 30
MAIN:   
    MOVLW .6    
    MOVWF N1    
    MOVLW .10   
    CLRF RL 
    CLRF RH 

UP:     ADDWF RL ;RL=W+RL       
    BTFSC STATUS,C ; CHECK C FLAG IN STATUS 
    INCF RH         ;IF(C==1 THEN RH=RH+1) ;
    DECFSZ N1       ;N1=N1-1 ;Декрементация
    GOTO UP         ;IF(N1!=0) THEN GOTO UP LABEL
    
ADD:
    MOVLW .23   
    ADDWF RL    
    CLRW        
    MOVLW .101
    SUBWF RL 
   HERE:    GOTO HERE
    END
```

I'm using MPLAB IDE.

Comment: What hardware do you plan to use so the user can input A with ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate memory in PIC assembly you can do it this whay;

```
Bank_0    udata 0x020
  A            RES 1                    ;reserve 1 Byte at address 0x20
  B            RES 1                    ;reserve 1 Byte at address 0x21
  C            RES 1                    ;reserve 1 Byte at address 0x22
```

Or use the shared bank

```
Bank0_shr  udata_shr 0x70
  W_safe       RES 1                  ;reserve 1 Byte at address 0x70
```

You can do the input of a value e.g.  in binary format over a controller port.